# Как связать Html с Css?

Tags: html, css

Я никак не могу связать страницу с таблицей, созданной в CSS.

Comment: Спасибо , получилось 

Comment: @Nadya, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 8):

Полагаю, необходим обобщающий ответ, чтобы новички, пришедшие сюда за ответом, получили полную информацию с примерами.

Имеется 4 способа.

---

### 1. Встроенные стили

Подключение встроенных или `inline` стилей заключается в применении атрибута *`style`* к определённому тегу на странице. В этом случае значением атрибута является одно или несколько (через точку с запятой) свойств CSS с соответствующими значениями. Как правило, такой способ используется в тех случаях, когда надо изменить характеристики конкретного элемента на одной странице.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Подключение встроенных стилей</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p style="color:#ff0066; text-align:center">Параграф 1</p>
  <p style="color:#0066ff; font-size:120%">Параграф 2</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

---

### 2. Внутренние стили

Внутренние стили указываются между тегами `<head></head>` и подключаются с помощью тега `<style>`. В этом случае CSS воздействует уже не на один элемент, а на все указанные в стилях элементы, которые имеются на данной странице. Обычно данный способ применяется, когда необходимо изменить стили сразу у нескольких одинаковых элементов в пределах одной HTML-страницы.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Подключение встроенных стилей</title>
  <style type="text/css">
   body {
    background: #ccccff; /* цвет фона страницы */
   }
   p {
    color: red; /* цвет текста параграфов */
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; /* гарнитура шрифта параграфов */
    font-size: 150%; /* размер шрифта */
    text-align: center; /* текст по центру */
    border: 5px green double; /* стили рамки */
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>Параграф 1</p>
  <p>Параграф 2</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

---

### 3. Внешние стили

Внешние стили подключаются отдельным файлом при помощи тега `<link>`. В этом случае все стили располагаются в обычном текстовом файле с расширением `.css` и влияют на элементы всех страниц, к которым этот файл подключается. Обычно создание стилей сайта начинается именно этим способом, так как только с его помощью ощущаются все плюсы CSS, ведь изменяя данные всего в одном файле можно управлять отображением сразу большого числа страниц. А уже в процессе работы над сайтом добавляются внутренние или встроенные стили, если это необходимо.

В первом блоке содержимое файла `style.css`, находящегося в папке `style`:

```css
body {
 background: #ccccff; /* цвет фона страницы */
}
p {
 color: red; /* цвет текста параграфов */
 font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; /* гарнитура шрифта параграфов */
 font-size: 150%; /* размер шрифта */
 text-align: center; /* текст по центру */
 border: 5px green double; /* стили рамки */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Подключение внешних стилей</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>Параграф 1</p>
  <p>Параграф 2</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

---

### 4. Через правило @import

Это правило служит для объединения нескольких таблиц стилей в одну. Чтобы правило `@import` правильно работало, оно обязательно должно указываться в самом начале таблицы стилей, единственное исключение — правило `@charset` .

```css
@import url("https://kristinitatest.github.io/Stack%20Exchange/HTML+CSS/1.css");
@import url("https://kristinitatest.github.io/Stack%20Exchange/HTML+CSS/2.css");
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <title>Внешние стили с @import</title>
     </head>
     <body>
      <p>Содержимое страницы.</p>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 6):

в head вашего html пишете

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="путь_к_css_файлу" />
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<head>
  ...
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="путь к файлу/style.css">
  ...
</head>
```

Answer (score 3):

Есть ещё два способа:

```
<style type="text/css">
/*Тут ваш код например:*/
body{
background-color: black;
}
</style>
```

и через аттрибут `style` всех тегов например:

`<div style="position:absolute;top:5px;left:2px;"></div>`

или

`<a style="border: none;" href=""></a>`

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего подключать через тег

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
```

Другие способы [как подключить CSS к HTML](https://domhtml.ru/kak-podklyuchit-css-k-html/) можно прочитать на сайте

Comment: https://domhtml.ru/kak-podklyuchit-css-k-html/

Answer (score 0):

*К слову, коллеги выше описали все методы.* Скорее всего вы не можете присоединить через местоположение **файла стилей**. Или же назовите него не русскими буквами. :3

```
<link href="здесь надо указать путь, считая, что index.html находится в корневой папке" rel="stylesheet"> 
<!-- type="text/css" принято не писать в HTML5 -->
```